# How can i remove this weird Focus (TinyMCE)

Tags: internet-explorer-9, tinymce

First of all, let me show you the problem.
[image of error](http://tldr.me/1tj1f95.gif)

The white box is the TinyMCE editor. Default it is readonly.
When editing the editor shows it's controls and it gains focus.
After coming out of editing mode, the editor somehow keeps its focus, showing in (1).

This wouldn't be so much a problem if it didn't lead to the following problem:

When the focus is there, the first button that gets pressed, does not trigger (any of (2)).
If i first click the body of the screen, or a different button after the first one, this triggers.

I tried setting focus in the codebehind (C#), but this didn't make any difference.
Another attempt I made, by adding jQuery to set focus to the first visible input, didn't remove the cursor in position (1) either.

I hope someone here knows the trick to get rid of this focus somehow :)

Comment: +1 can you show us a live demo of your problem?

Comment: Unfotunately I don't have administrator access to my development PC.
Also, the screens show some personal information (hence the censoring).

Actually I just found an example here on stackoverflow: enter (or edit) a comment, then just press enter. The cursor will remain on the topleft of the comments for the post, and the first button you click will not trigger (this button can be pressed as often as you want). Clicking anywhere else will once again allow you to click buttons.

Comment: @Thariama of course this happens only in IE9 (not in IE7 or 8). Also i found out it happens to links as well.

Comment: you may file a bugreport here: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with an older version of TinyMCE (v3.4b3) and upgrading is not an option. I did notice this is fixed in the latest version (v3.5.7) so I was hoping perhaps someone knew of a workaround. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: @Thariama I've convinced my boss to run the latest version of TinyMCE alongside the old one. If you make an answer wich tells me to upgrade, I'd be happyp to mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use the latest stable version of tinymce.